# What if anything should be done about an answered question that has been removed by the author?

Tags: discussion

This morning I checked my inbox and found a comment that seemed to indicate that the users problem was resolved. Upon attempting to read the entire comment from the post at https://askubuntu.com/questions/469844/upgrade-problem-dpkg-dependencies-netbase-4-47ubuntu1-all-deb I got a page not found and an indication that the question was removed by the author. What if anything should be done in a situation such as this?

Comment: The main point to remember: comments are 2nd class citizens on all stackexchange sites - they get easily deleted in several ways.

Comment: Thank you. Understood. I do however review my Inbox as often as possible and the inbox doesn't seem to allow reading the entire comment. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The comment suggests it wasn't answered. Here it is in full.

> hey, thank you, I ran again `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` at this stage the upgrade failed because of `var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-generic....deb`, I then ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`  and then upgrading again, however I could not solve the problem and linux-image was not installed completely... Thanks ..

If you'd posted the answer as a comment and they deleted it, I'd open it back up and invite you to post as an answer...

But in this case they seem to have given up. There's a 7 minute window between commenting and deleting. Getting a -1 on your first ever post probably doesn't help things.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up somewhat. All I got was "hey, thank you, I ran again sudo apt-get install -f, then sudo apt-get upgrade." I can see how getting a minus one on a first post could be distressing.  the question remains. "What if anything should be done in a situation such as this?"